# Latex to NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, math, nsstring, latex, nsattributedstring

Is there a library available that will turn Latex or another maths notation and turn it into a good-looking NSAttributedString? I have seen [AttributedMarkdown](https://github.com/dreamwieber/AttributedMarkdown) and other Markdown-to-NSAttributedString or Markdown-to-HTML (which can be converted to NSAttributedString) libraries. But what about latex?

Answer (score 1):

This
http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/
is written in c++ so it should compile in Xcode, you could use it to transform it to xml or change it altogether to create NSAttributedString right away. Hope it helps...

Comment: Is its license similar to the BSD or MIT licenses? I need to know if I can use it in my closed-source project, and I don't read french...

Comment: http://www.cecill.info/licences/Licence_CeCILL_V2-en.html english version here, I understand is GPL like.